# Long lines in code break layout of revisions page

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, revision-history

[This first revision of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65262500/revisions) has a very long line in a code section (no linebreaks). Instead of showing horizontal scrollbars, the preview of the post content does overflow the revisions page. This is how it looks for me:

[image: Very messed up table]

Only after noticing the huge horizontal scrollbar I figured why the table of revisions doesn't show authors or edit messages properly. This is the whole page:

[image: Whole page]

Comment: @CodyGray thanks a lot, that question somehow escaped my search terms.

Comment: No worries. It has also apparently escaped the developers, too...

Comment: PS: it's really weird to be at the receiving end of the new close message and not seeing who voted to close. Good the timeline is readily accessible now…

Comment: Oh, weird. I thought users who had close-vote privileges themselves were always shown the close voters.

Comment: That's what I thought… and I think I had tried it out when they introduced this. Maybe has changed since.